# In iOS 17, UIPopoverPresentationController/UIPopoverController has an extra or multiple border for UIView. Does anyone face this same issue in iOS 17?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, ios17

I have used below code in UIViewController's **viewWillLayoutSubviews()** method to add border to UIView.

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {   
        guard let shapeLayer = view.superview?.superview?.mask?.layer as? CAShapeLayer else { return }
        let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        borderLayer.path = shapeLayer.path
        borderLayer.lineWidth = 1
        borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#2B2B2B")?.cgColor
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.frame = shapeLayer.bounds
        view.superview?.superview?.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
```

**Output screenshot(it's showing multiple border line in iOS17)**

Not Working in iOS17[image: ][1]]

Working in iOS16 or lower OS[image]

Comment: `viewWillLayoutSubviews` can be called many times. That's not a good place to add a layer. It's a good place to size the layer, but don't add it there.

Comment: Did you put the same image twice by mistake?

Comment: Sorry @Sweeper, it's updated now

Comment: @HangarRash, but same code working in iOS16 or lower

Comment: Well, Apple might have changed the number of times or order in which the hook is called. As @HangarRash said you cannot make assumptions here. If we cannot change the place where it is called you should give the layer a `name` and remove it (if it was added before) before adding it (again) or try to reuse the layer by accessing it via the name

Comment: Also, make sure your call `super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. Unless the documentation explicitly states otherwise, whenever you override a method, always call `super.xxx()` in the overridden method.